# save output to text file without overwriting & Printing N entries in a matrix [matlab]

Tags: matlab, save

I want to save my result of functions in a text file.That can be done using the following ways in malab:

1. Using Printf

   ```
         fileID = fopen('testdata.txt', 'w');
         fprintf(fileID, '%d %d %d\n', v);
         fclose(fileID);
   ```
2. Using Save

   ```
         save('testdata.txt', 'v', '-ascii');
   ```

But the problem is using the two methods that if the function is repeated the file is beeing **overwriten** how to fix that? **I need all the outputs from the 10 runs**.

Here are some examples:
A% USING PRINTF
        v = [3 6 9];

```
    >> fileID = fopen('testdata.txt', 'w');
       fprintf(fileID, '%d %d %d\n', v);
       fclose(fileID);
```

OUTPUT of file (line 1): 3 6 9

```
       >> v= [1 2 3];
       >> fileID = fopen('testdata.txt', 'w');
          fprintf(fileID, '%d %d %d\n', v);
          fclose(fileID);
```

OUTPUT of file (line 1) : 1 2 3 (the file is overwriten)

B %USING SAVE

```
       >> save('testdata.txt', 'v', '-ascii');
```

OUTPUT of file (line 1): 1.0000000e+000  2.0000000e+000  3.0000000e+000

```
       >> v = [3 6 9];
       >> save('testdata.txt', 'v', '-ascii');
```

OUTPUT of file (line 1): 3.0000000e+000  6.0000000e+000  9.0000000e+000

---

```
                            **Printing N values**
```

V in the above example is 3 entries: If there exist N entries for sure there is a way to display them right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
                for i= 1:4;
                fileID = fopen('testdata.txt', 'at');
                fprintf(fileID, 'this is answer %d\n',i);
                fprintf(fileID, '%5.3e\n', v{i});
                fclose(fileID);
                end
```

Answer in notepad:

```
       this is answer 1
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       0.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       this is answer 2
       1.000e+000
       0.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       this is answer 3
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       0.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       this is answer 4
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       0.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
       1.000e+000
```

Comment: Thanks @Richante but if I have N entries and want to display them in a line am I obliged to write '%5.3e, (Ntimes)\n' !!!!!

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file, use

```
fileID = fopen('testdata.txt', 'a');
```

with 'a' instead of 'w'. This will append to that file. See: [fopen](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html).

Comment: for v=[3 6 9] and v=[13 16 19] this is the output:3 6 913 16 19. how to display v2 on the next line?in this way it is read 913 and not 9 13...